# Upper bound on trace formula

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, trace

I am trying to prove that this quantity: $f(W) = trace((C^T\circ(W^T - W'^T))(W'-W)(XX^T))$ is smooth. $\circ$ is the Hadamard product. Smoothness is satisfied if  $ f(W)\le H\|W - W' \|^2$. $H$ is a constant. $\| .\|$ is any norm.

I am very close to do it, however, I am struggling in dealing with Hadamard product inside a trace.

Comment: What do you mean by $A\circ B$? Is that a Hadamard product?

Comment: @BenGrossmann that is right.

Comment: Is $\|\cdot\|$ a Frobenius norm or a spectral norm?

Comment: @BenGrossmann It does not matter I think. It is just any norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)). If $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the Frobenius norm, then we have $\|W\| = \|\operatorname{vec}(W)\|$, and we can apply the following facts:

1. $\operatorname{vec}(A \circ B) = \operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(A)) B$,
2. $\operatorname{tr}(A^T B) = \operatorname{vec}(A)^T\operatorname{vec}(B)$,
3. $\operatorname{vec}(AB) = (B^T \otimes I)\operatorname{vec}(A)$.

With that, we can rewrite
$$
\operatorname{tr}((C^T\circ(W^T - W'^T))(W'-W)(XX^T)) =\\ 
\operatorname{vec}(W' - W)^T 
\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(C))((XX^T) \otimes I)
\operatorname{vec}(W' - W).
$$
With the inequality $x^TAx \leq \sigma_{\max}(A) \|x\|^2$, we can therefore conclude that
$$
\operatorname{tr}((C^T\circ(W^T - W'^T))(W'-W)(XX^T)) \leq 
\\
\sigma_{\max}(\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(C))((XX^T) \otimes I)) \cdot \|W - W'\|^2.
$$

---

Another less computation-intensive approach: for $W \neq W'$, note that $\frac{f(W)}{\|W - W'\|^2} = f(Y)$, where $Y = W' + \frac{W - W'}{\|W - W'\|}$. Note that every matrix of the from $A = \frac{W - W'}{\|W - W'\|}$ satisfies $\|A\| = 1$.

With that in mind, let $S$ denote the set
$$
S = \{Y: Y = W' + A \text{ and } \|A\| = 1\}.
$$
Note that $S$ is compact (closed and bounded). Thus, the continuous function $f$ must attain a maximum over $S$. In other words, there exists a $k > 0$ such that for all $W \neq W'$, we have
$$
\frac{f(W)}{\|W - W'\|^2} \leq k \implies f(W) \leq k \cdot \|W - W'\|^2.
$$
Trivially, this second inequality holds for $W = W'$ as well.

---

Regarding the explicit computation of an upper bound: note that
$$
\sigma_{\max}(\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(C))((XX^T) \otimes I)) \leq \\
\sigma_{\max}(\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(C)))
\cdot \sigma_{\max}(((XX^T) \otimes I)) = \\
\left[\max_{i,j} |C_{ij}| \right]\cdot \sigma_{\max}(X)^2. 
$$
Most computational software will have a reasonably efficient method for computing $\sigma_{\max}(X)$.

Comment: Thanks. This is another question but $XX^T$ is almost impossible to compute since it will result in a huge dense matrix. $X\in n\times k, n > 1\times10^6$. Do you have an idea how to simplify it?

Comment: @rando Does it matter if your upper-bound is tight? Also, how big $k$ relative to $n$? Would a $k \times k$ matrix be more manageable?

Comment: @rando If you're asking about "simplifying" the function, then you could rewrite it as
$$
f(W) = \operatorname{tr}(X^T(C^T\circ(W^T - W'^T))(W'-W)X),
$$
which is the trace of a $k \times k$ matrix. Does that help?

Comment: I meant to simplify the intensive calculation. $n \gg k$, $k$ does not exceed $100$'s.

Comment: @rando Are you saying that you want to compute the specific upper bound that I have given? Or, is it enough to have any upper-bound $H$? There are other upper bounds that are easier to compute

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I want to calculate $H$. So, I'd prefer to have $H$ that is not computationally intensive. $X \in n\times k, n \gg k, k $ is small. So any matrix multiplication that results in a $n\times n$ matrix is not possible. $C$ is a sparse binary matrix, so a multiplication of a form $C \circ XX^T$ is feasible. The upper bound $vec(C)(XX^T\dots)$ is not manageable I think.    Calculating the max singular value of a sparse matrix is manageable. So, $\sigma_{max}(C\circ XX^T)$ is ok.

Comment: I think you've addressed my concern in your recent edits. Thanks!